# Passing icons on NotificationContent in AwesomeNotifications package (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am unable to pass an icon to the NotificationContent.
I am making a chat app where I want to show user's profile picture (fetched from network) as the icon for the notification.

But,  whenever I pass it in the NotificationContent, I get the error:

"**Small icon ('https:///') must be a valid media native resource type.**"

The code is I used is:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: ID.generateRandomInt(3),
    groupKey: group.key,
    channelKey: channel.key,
    icon: "https://prod-ripcut-delivery.disney-plus.net/v1/variant/disney/174C605829DEB3C79C2F6993EFA97B2ECBF21D6A152E6BB0CA00DDA987E94BAC/scale?width=1200&aspectRatio=1.78&format=jpeg",
    title: title,
    body: body,
  ),
  actionButtons: [
    NotificationActionButton(key: "markAsRead", label: "Mark As Read"),
    NotificationActionButton(key: "reply", label: "Reply")
  ],
);
```

It would be great if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel like its the size of the image that's triggering the error. Is there any way I can modify the size if image is fetched from network. Please do let me know if anyone thinks there is some other reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

`icon` doesn't support network images.

> must be a resource image

`largeIcon` supports network images.

See `NotificationContent` in [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications).

Comment: Is there any other way I can show the profile picture of the user in the notification?

Comment: Use largeIcon instead.